# translator in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, translation

I am trying to develop an application able to translate a word in different languages. What are the  option (based on free dictionnaries is possible) for a cocoa application?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with something simple and investigate using a webservice to do it for me, like http://translate.google.com.  Then my code would be to simply package up the text, send it off to the servers, and wait for a response (which is how [Google's API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/) works).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was looking for soemthing which could be used offline.